# Select a input field in jquery based on name

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-selectors, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using jquery form validator to validate all my fields in the form.

In form validator I am using following code to see if a input field has the name `minExperience`.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if(/*Want to check if the `element` has the name = "minExperience"*/) 
    {
        error.insertAfter($('#skillBtn'));
    }
}
```

So that I can place the error message after `$('#skillBtn')`.

I am not able to figure out what to write in the if condition.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if(element.attr('name')=='minExperience') 
    {
        error.insertAfter($('#skillBtn'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one more question: How do I select this label: `<label for="minExperience">Experience</label>`

Comment: You can use `if(element.attr('name')=='minExperience' || $('label').attr('for')=="minExperience")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$('input[name=\'name_field\']').val()` and then compare it depends your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for `<input name="minExperience" />` you can do

```
alert($('input[name="minExperience"]').val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put as

```
 if (element.attr("name") == "minExperience")
 {
           error.insertAfter($('#skillBtn'));
 }
```

Comment: How could I have? We probably checked the same source. I checked the Jquery site for references and provided the snippet here.